# Is there anything like Unity's "lenses" in GNOME 3?

Tags: unity, gnome-shell, lenses

The lenses were the best things in Ubuntu's history in my opinion. Is there any possibility to get this with a new distro?

Comment: Could you please expand a bit more on what exactly you're looking for? Someone like me who hasn't used Unity for a long time might come up with interesting suggestions if it is understood what exactly you seek. Simulating "lenses" on GNOME may not be possible, but there might be something similar. For example there are ways to search Google or Wikipedia directly from GNOME shell.

Comment: You still can install `ubuntu-unity-desktop` and get lenses back :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to install lenses in gnome3. But I have a solution for you.
It is possible to install more then one desktop interface. As you know, Ubuntu has been using gnome3 since version 17.10, but it is possible to install unity next to gnome3.

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-unity-desktop-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Regards.

Comment: Not an answer to the specific question. The question is: can we do something similar in Gnome 3? The answer can be a yes, a no, or something in between.